# Determining when a page anchor (#) visit has occurred with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently intercepting when a user clicks a particular link with jQuery and scrolling them to an anchor on the page. Once the page has scrolled to the anchor, I then want to show a div and focus on an element in that div. The following code does this but with a problem...

```
// Intercept the click on the link which scrolls to the signup form
$('#section-footer-buttons a').click(function(){
    // Scroll to the welcome section
    location.href = '#welcome';

    // Show the hidden signup form if it's not already visible
    $('#signup-form').slideDown(350, function(){
        // Focus on the first element on the form now the animation is complete
        $('#signup-form :input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
    });

    // We've handled this click so return false
        return false;
});
```

The problem is that by the time the page has scrolled up to the anchor where the signup form is, the hidden div is already visible without the nice slideDown animation. Is there a way to only begin the slideDown animation once the page has stopped scrolling? Essentially, I need a callback from when location.href has completed.

Comment: isn't the scroll instant? Why are you doing the `location.href = '#welcome';` with javascript instead of just giving he anchor tag `href="#welcome"` and allowing the default action to take care of the scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You should come at this a different way.

```
$('#section-footer-buttons a').click(function(){
    var welcome = '#welcome',
        $offset = $('[href="'+welcome+'"]').offset().top;

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$offset,350
    },function(){
        location.href = welcome;

        $('#signup-form').slideDown(350, function(){
            $(this).find('input').filter(':enabled:visible').first().focus();
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

Making use of the `.animate()` callback function like this should hopefully give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I should add that I am using `fullpage.js` to scroll to different sections of the page, rather than jQuery's animate(method)